What is fastest way of finding all indices that "contains" a value between the interval?
Suppose I have two arrays of same length (N), x and y. They satisfy following conditions:

x[i] is strictly smaller than y[i].
No a priori information on the interval length y[i]-x[i]. Although, it is usually far smaller than max(x)-min(x) or max(y)-min(y).
Either x[i] or y[i] can be sorted. However, to have any meaning, original pairs of x[i] and y[i] should be preserved. Thus, x[i] and y[i] cannot be sorted simultaneously.

Now, I have a value z. For some indices i, x[i]<=z<y[i] is satisfied. How do I find all such indices? Obviously I could loop over all 0...N-1 to check all cases, but given the condition 2, it is extremely wasteful. If it were just to find the closest indices, binary search would work well, but varying intervel length is problematic.
One approach I've thought of is, first sort either x or y, then use binary search to get the first element to iterate. For example, if I sort x, then I know exactly when x exceeds z. Then, I have to iterate from 0 to that maximum index. Instead of iterating over entire N elements, I could iterate about a half of them -- which still isn't useful.
Any suggestions to approach this? Especially, what I want to do is find such indices for not just one number z but another array of numbers, respectively, and I am not sure if this changes the problem.

Do a quickselect rather than a sort. That should give you both the rank of z in x, and the O(log(n)) ranges where smaller values of x[i] are found.
A quickselect in each will get the whole ansaer in something like O(log(n)^2).
